# Using openParentApplication: and handleWatchKitExtensionRequest: to send location updates to Watch App not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using `openParentApplication:` and `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:` to ask for, and send an NSNumber object that contains a value from the Core Location `locationManager:didUpdateLocation:` method. I am doing this so that my watchkit app doesn't have to worry about using Core Location, and I can use all the logic that I already wrote in my iOS app. The callback to my watchkit extension seems to work correctly, and I get a response back in my "reply:" callback.

However, I never get any real data from Core Location until I manually tap my apps icon in the Simulator. THEN I start getting real data from Core Location and my watch kit interface is updated with correct data.

Is this just a limitation of the Simulator?

Comment: can I ask how did you pass the location from didUpdateLocations to the reply of handleWatchKitExtensionRequest: ?

Comment: Just have a property in that `viewController` that can be accessed from your app delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` rather than `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`. Doing so allowed me to get location updates how I wanted.

Comment: not sure what the logic behind but trick also worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want Core Location in your watch app you will want to do it in your extension.  You can put your code for `locationManager:didUpdateLocation:` in a common framework or put that file in both your iOS and WatchKit extension targets so that the code can be shared.

Comment: So there is no way to be able to go back and forth between the app and Watchkit App seamlessly? I basically have to build the functionality of core location and core data into both of them? It is a shame I couldn't just call all of the methods in the parent application that I have already taken the time to build.

Comment: You can go back and forth between an app and the extension.  You can have your extension open your iOS app in the background and then use MMWormHole to communicate between the two.  So I guess you could use that to pass your location data from your app to your extension.